# Swift shardApplication().openURL() with data URI

Tags: swift, nsurl, data-uri, openurl, data-uri-scheme

So I have a `String` with the template of

```
let dataURI = 'data:MIMEType;base64,DATA'
```

where the data is filled with a bunch of base64 representing the file I want to open. This url will load in a WKWebView or UIWebView; however, when I try to take the same URL and open it via

```
let uri = NSURL(string: dataURI)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(uri)
```

I get the error

```
LaunchServices: ERROR: There is no registered handler for URL scheme data
```

I also attempted a string with the format of

```
let uristring = 'data://' + dataURI
```

which gets the same error.

Any ideas whats going on here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS only contains handlers for a few URL schemes (notably `http`, `mailto`, `tel`, and `sms`). Unfortunately it doesn't come with built-in support for the `data` scheme. Because of this, the OS doesn't know that it can pass your data to Safari to be displayed.

You can find more information on Inter-App Communication [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html) and all of the schemes supported natively by iOS [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899).

Comment: Thanks, I did a work around by using WebViews because I didn't want to leave this over the weekend.